# Java parse a number in exponential format

Tags: java, parsing

I'm having a real hard time trying to convert the String

```
-8.70395364652618e-02
```

or a similar quantity from a `String` to a `double`. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

I may have been hasty in asking, but does this look like a good approach?

```
double val = new BigDecimal(string).doubleValue();
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't know why you need code for that question

Comment: @msrd0 partly to show that the OP has made some effort and partly to understand what the exact question we are answering is. i.e. is it "why does my number change when I turn it into a double" or is it "how to parse a `String` into a double".

Comment: @BenQuinton-Kindly upvote and accept the answer which helps you the most!

Comment: @shekharsuman this is a bit premature.

Comment: @BoristheSpider-I think your answer should be rewarded for explaining both to OP as well as msrd0 ! Also,I ain't promoting my answer. Lastly,nothing better can be added I guess!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, `double` is **not** infinitely precise. The number you have will be represented by the *closest* `double` value - your number is representable as a `double`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal("-8.70395364652618e-02");
    System.out.println(val);
    System.out.println(val.doubleValue());
}
```

Output:

```
-0.0870395364652618
-0.0870395364652618
```

So the standard parsing methods will work:

```
String val = "-8.70395364652618e-02";
System.out.println(Double.valueOf(val));
System.out.println(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(val)));
```

The difference being is that `Double.valueOf` will return a `Double` (the object wrapper) and `Double.parseDouble` will return a `double` (the primitive type).

Comment: Note that the JVM doesn't really care about having a `double`or a `Double` if they are casted to one of both - the only difference is that a `Double` can be `null` in that case, a `double` can't

Comment: @msrd0 the JVM _does_ care - allocating a `Double` wrapper will cost time & memory; this can have a bearing in mathematical programming. Further `Double` has some very useful methods on it - `double` (obviously) does not.

Comment: @msrd0-Your comment stands totally absurd,please study more about primitives and reference data-types!

Comment: Of course, but from the JavaDoc I referred in my answer there is no difference between calling one of `Double.valueOf` and `Double.parseDouble` - it doesn't matter where `Double` was automatically casted to a `double`, the `Double` Object will be allocated in both ways

Comment: @msrd0-Though this question has probably nothing to do with `double` vs `Double`,but,as a generalised case you should always put correct standard facts,not the special cases!

Comment: @shekharsuman I maybe miss-formulated my first comment, check it again (I'm no native speaker, sorry)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Double.valueOf()`. This method will parse your String for things like that. For more information, see the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) of `Double.valueOf`.

As *herrlock* correctly mentioned in his comment, you could also use `Double.parseDouble()` as well, but I would use the first method, cause of the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-) of `parseDouble()`:

> Returns a new double initialized to the value represented by the specified String, as performed by the valueOf method of class Double.